# Cuando el $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] no tiene Valor, ¿cómo le asigno uno automático?

Tags: php

Hola esto es un poco de programación básica pero no me esta resultado, quiero poder enviar un valor mediante el `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` pero si este esta vacío que tome uno por default lo he visto en otra parte pero no me esta funcionado, no sé el porqué. Me echan una mano. Gracias.

```
if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) || !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])?'1rBgRZTK6E6reM4Su6YtI5kDHMWg6bn6Z':$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])
{
        echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
}
```

Comment: Lo que estás pidiendo se llama [Operador Ternario](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). En PHP es: `$var = (operacion_condicional) ? valor_verdadero : valor_falso`. Esta expresión no se pone dentro de `if`, ya que el `if` está implícito en el ternario.

Comment: En PHP7 es el *Operador de Fusión de null*: `if( $_SERVER['clave'] ?? 'valor' )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según yo no se pueden añadir operadores como && u || en un if ternario. Lo que podrías hacer es retirar el isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']), ya que la función empty() te valida si la variable tiene o no un valor. Quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
!empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = '1rBgRZTK6E6reM4Su6YtI5kDHMWg6bn6Z';
echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Comment: Considera añadir una explicación a tu código, pues sin explicación, puede llegar a funcionar para el OP, pero no entenderá cómo.

Comment: @Rodrigo Ya edité mi respuesta, gracias por la retro

Comment: Si, esa es la solucion que estoy usando, pero si te fijas y como he visto se puede super simplificar en una sola linea similar a esta if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) || !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])?'1rBgRZTK6E6reM4Su6YtI5kDHMWg6bn6Z':$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) busco al genio que sabe manejar este estilo de programacion pues nos ahorra tiempo y la respuesta es mas rapida.

Comment: @Torronf edité mi respuesta, espero y ahora si te ayude.

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo.